# one button change language flutter

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am building a website with flutter, and I am using [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization/install) package, and there is two button one for Arabic Language to change to arabic locale context, And one for English Language to change to English context, what I want is only one button to check for the current locale context, for example if the locale context is Arabic then the button will display English text. else will display English locale context and the button will display Arabic Text.

here is my code:

```
> main.dart

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      child: MyApp(),
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('ar'),
      ],
      assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
      path: 'assets/translations'));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //the root of the application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      locale: context.locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the buttons I'm using to change the locale context:

```
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await (context.setLocale(Locale('ar'))),
                child: Text('عربي')),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await (context.setLocale(Locale('en'))),
                child: Text('English')),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
context.locale.languageCode == 'en'
? ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await (context.setLocale(Locale('ar'))),
                child: Text('عربي')),
: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await (context.setLocale(Locale('en'))),
                child: Text('English')),
```

Comment: Yes that's correct, I solved it yesterday, anyways I appreciate your answer thank you.